# Should the scroll-behavior, overflow-anchor and overflow-y CSS properties be set on html or body?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I want to always show the scrollbar, have smooth scrolling enabled for the entire page and disable the new overflow-anchor functionality.

Is this best set on the `html` tag:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

or on the `body` tag?

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Please explain which is preferred and why. Thank you!

Comment: Partial answer `scroll-behavior:smooth` has no effect on `body` element if you are browsing with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

> Add scroll-behavior: smooth to the `html` element to enable smooth
>   scrolling for the whole page (note: it is also possible to add it to a
>   specific element/scroll container)

You can get refrence form [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2) and info about browser compatibility also

and [overflow-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor) property can be applied to `all elements`